# Wrong listview attributes removed with changing data set

Tags: android, android-listview

I just implemented this swipe-to-delete [solution](https://github.com/romannurik/Android-SwipeToDismiss).

I display data in the ListView from a Rails API (my own), and use the swipe to both remove the item from the ListView, and to make a network call deleting the item from the database. I put the ID for each item in the listview in a hidden `TextView` and pull that ID when I send the request so the server side knows which item to delete:

```
// all in onCreate()
SwipeDismissListViewTouchListener touchListener = 
                new SwipeDismissListViewTouchListener(
                        listView,
                        new SwipeDismissListViewTouchListener.DismissCallbacks() {
                            @Override
                            public boolean canDismiss(int position) {
                                return true;
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onDismiss(ListView listView, int[] reverseSortedPositions) {
                                for (int position : reverseSortedPositions) {

                                    TextView listItemId = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.list_item_id);

                                    String deleteId = listItemId.getText().toString();

                                    //volley delete call
                                    deleteListItem(deleteId);

                                    shoppingListItems.remove(listAdapter.getItem(position));

                                }

                                listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }
                        });

        listView.setOnTouchListener(touchListener);
```

Here is the volley call:

```
public void deleteListItem(String item_id) {

        String deleteUrl = "http://polar-beach-6028.herokuapp.com/api/v1/list_items/" + item_id;

        JsonObjectRequest deleteRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.DELETE, deleteUrl, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                            if (response.getBoolean("success")) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "List item deleted.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Log.d("Error.Response", e.toString());
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Could not delete list item.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.d("Error.response", error.toString());
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Could not delete list item.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }) {
                @Override
                public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                    HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    headers.put("Content-Type",  "application/json");
                    headers.put("auth_token", mPreferences.getString("AuthToken", "") );
                    return headers;
                }
        };

        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(deleteRequest);
    }
```

My layout for items in the listview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/feed_bg"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_item_id"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone" />

   <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"

        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/feed_item_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/feed_item_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/feed_item_margin"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_parent_rounded_corner"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/feed_item_padding_top_bottom"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/feed_item_padding_top_bottom" >

       <TextView
            android:id="@+id/product"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/feed_item_status_pad_left_right"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/feed_item_status_pad_left_right"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/feed_item_status_pad_top" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/feed_item_padding_left_right"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/feed_item_padding_left_right" >

            <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
                android:id="@+id/itemImg"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/feed_item_vendor_pic_width"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/feed_item_vendor_pic_height"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter" >
            </com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView>


        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/store_name"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/feed_item_status_pad_left_right"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/feed_item_status_pad_left_right"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/feed_item_status_pad_top" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

It works beautifully on the first delete, however after the data set changes the network calls(using Volley) begin sending requests with the wrong `listItemId`. The result is that the wrong list items get deleted, and as the list gets deleted I end up getting errors on the server side because Volley is sending delete requests for items that have already been deleted mistakenly. I'm not sure why this is happening, any help? I'm happy to post other code if it will help, but will leave it at this for brevity.

**UPDATE**

Here is my parent xml layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#ffffff">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/shopping_list_show"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following call is likely the culprit:

```
TextView listItemId = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.list_item_id);
```

By not specifying where `R.id.list_item_id` should be looked up, you are trying to find it in the activity's layout - not in the listview item's layout.

From what you describe, you should be facing a `NullPointerException` when this executes:

```
String deleteId = listItemId.getText().toString();
```

But, since you are not reporting a NPE, I suspect that you have a TextView with id `R.id.list_item_id` in your activity's layout.

---

What you need to access the 'gone' textview (holding item id) is the list item view. So, let's try to tailor the code you got from - [here](https://github.com/romannurik/Android-SwipeToDismiss).

The callback interface you are using is this one:

```
public interface DismissCallbacks {

    // Called to determine whether the given position can be dismissed.
    boolean canDismiss(int position);

    // Called when the user has indicated they she would like to dismiss 
    // one or more list item positions.
    void onDismiss(ListView listView, int[] reverseSortedPositions);
}
```

As you can see, it is not providing you with everything you need. Let's fix this to return all relevant information. The edit will go into `SwipeDismissListViewTouchListener.java` (line 104):

```
public interface DismissCallbacks {

    // Called to determine whether the given position can be dismissed.
    boolean canDismiss(int position);

    // Called when the user has indicated they she would like to dismiss 
    // one or more list item positions.
    // Item ids are also returned.
    void onDismiss(ListView listView, int[] reverseSortedPositions, String[] itemIds);
}
```

`PendingDismissData` holds the `View` and list `position` of the list item being dismissed. We can extract the `item id` like this:

Edit the method `performDismiss(View, int)` in `SwipeDismissListViewTouchListener`:

```
public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
    --mDismissAnimationRefCount;
    if (mDismissAnimationRefCount == 0) {
         // No active animations, process all pending dismisses.
         // Sort by descending position
         Collections.sort(mPendingDismisses);

         int[] dismissPositions = new int[mPendingDismisses.size()];
---->>>  String[] itemIds = new String[mPendingDismisses.size()];

         for (int i = mPendingDismisses.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
             dismissPositions[i] = mPendingDismisses.get(i).position;

             // The view that holds the textview
             View dView = mPendingDismisses.get(i).view;

             // Find the textview in `dView`
             TextView listItemId = (TextView) dView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_id);

             // Add id to the array
---->>>      itemIds[i] = listItemId.getText().toString();
         }

         // Include the ids in the callback
         mCallbacks.onDismiss(mListView, dismissPositions, itemIds);

         ......
         ......
```

Your implementation will also change:

```
@Override
public void onDismiss(ListView listView, int[] reverseSortedPositions, String[] itemIds) {
    for (int i = 0; i < reverseSortedPositions.length; i++) {
        //volley delete call
        deleteListItem(itemIds[i]);

        shoppingListItems.remove(listAdapter.getItem(reverseSortedPositions[i]));
    }

    listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

If this still doesn't fix your problem, please post your adapter code. There might be an issue with how your are assigning/updating values to the hidden textview.

Note: It would be better to include the item id in another manner - something that doesn't require you to use an extra textview. Perhaps, you can set the item id as a tag to the `convertView` and access it in `SwipeDismissListViewTouchListener`?

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly. I can award the bounty in ~7 hours. I don't actually have a TextView in my parent layout with id `R.id.list_item_id`, only in the child layout. I don't know why no NPE would be thrown there. As I said, it was deleting items on the server side, just the wrong ones. I'll post my parent layout to inspect.

Comment: @settheline You're very welcome. I looked at the activity layout. Its strange that server calls were getting through without an NPE from the prior statement - they both share the code block. In any case - glad you worked the problem out. As mentioned in the answer above, you can do without the textview. Here's how: I suppose you're using a custom adapter that extends `BaseAdapter`.  On the View that you return from `getView(...)`, set a tag using - `View#setTag(int, Object)` method. In the `performDismiss(...)` method, retrieve the `item id` using `View#getTag(int)`. Just an optimization..